# Sign Language Translator with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, classification, cascade

I have been working on `OpenCV` for sometime. Is there any way I can use its `CascadeClassifier` feature to sort of do a Sign Language Translator for my project by training the different signs used in Sign Language. Is this feasible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the cascadeclassifier for this might be a bad idea, as you'd have to train 1 cascade per gesture, and later have all cascades in memory and run them consecutively.

also, ASL contains 2 gestures, that include *movement* which will further complicate it.

imho, a contours based approach ( using e.g the hausdorff distance for classification ) might do much better.

the 3.0 ( master ) version of opencv has a [new shape module](http://docs.opencv.org/master/modules/shape/doc/shape.html), that might fit your needs